# Downloading an artifact from actions on someone else's repository

Tags: github

This problem seems really simple. I'm trying to download a pre-built binary for a program from somebody's github repo.

They suggest that I can do this:
"You can also download pre-built binaries from GitHub Actions artifacts."

But it turns out that I have no idea what that means!

The file is not in the actions page (I'm not sure if it should be) and when I try:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" https://api.github.com/repos/nbdd0121/wsld/actions/artifacts/42682371/zip
```

I receive `{ "message": "You must have the actions scope to download artifacts.", "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/actions#download-an-artifact" }`

But this documentation implies that I need to **Build an app** in order to **download a file**???

Can this possibly be correct?

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
curl.exe `
--netrc-file C:\Users\Steven\_netrc `
-L `
-o wsldhost.exe.zip `
https://api.github.com/repos/nbdd0121/wsld/actions/artifacts/42682371/zip
```

Where `_netrc` looks like this:

```
default login <USERNAME> password <PERSONAL ACCESS TOKEN>
```

https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact/issues/89

Answer (score 0):

You can also directly use [Basic auth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). In curl:

```
curl -L -u <USERNAME>:<PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN> -o artifact.zip https://api.github.com/repos/nbdd0121/wsld/actions/artifacts/42682371/zip
```

And the personal access token is generated at: https://github.com/settings/tokens